# Server cannot boot up

Tags: boot, reboot, redhat-enterprise-linux, ibm-server

My IBM server is running RHEL 6, and it cannot boot up. The BIOS seems to be OK (since I was able to go in to change the boot order), and during boot-up, it will stop at a black screen with a picture of a diskette, and arrows pointing to what seems like the F1 key. I'm not sure what this means, and multiple restarts gave me the same problem.

Comment: What model computer is it?  What's the make/model of the BIOS?  Have you checked all the connections?  Have there been any recent changes to or incidents involving this system?

Comment: It's a x3650. Nothing was changed to the server, but it wasn't accessed for about 2 months and when I tried to access it, I saw this error.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem in boot sector. If you have a partition table backup, restore it, otherwise there are applications to fix it. Some partition table editors can do it.

Comment: How do I restore the partition table backup? Sorry, but I'm not familiar with partitions.

Comment: You should backup it before. If you did not, then your choice is fixing `MBR` (master boot record) which seems to be overwritten incorrectly.